# Python Numpy integers high memory use

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to store 25 million integers efficiently in Python. Preferably using Numpy so I can perform operations on them afterwards.

The idea is to have them stored as 4-bytes unsigned integers. So the required memory should be 25M entries * 4 bytes = 95 MB.

I have written the following test code and the reported memory consumption is almost 700 MB, why?

```
a = np.array([], dtype=np.uint32)

# TEST MEMORY FOR PUTTING 25 MILLION INTEGERS IN MEMORY
for i in range(0, 25000000):
    np.append(a, np.asarray([i], dtype=np.uint32))
```

If I do this for example, it works as expected:

```
a = np.random.random_integers(1, 25000000, size=25000000)
```

Why?

Comment: One quick thing to try is using `xrange` instead of `range`. `range` consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: What's `lst`? Why aren't you saving the result of `np.append` anywhere? Show us actual, complete code you actually ran, and that we can paste into an interpreter session to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why not just use `np.arange`?

Comment: @jme ``np.arange`` also creates the complete array as soon as you access it.

Comment: lst should be a, sorry typo

Comment: You are aware that your `for`-loop code *doesn't* create an array with `25000000` integers, aren't you? You're just creating (and immediately discarding) a new 1-element array `25000000` times. If you wanted to build up a larger array, you'd need to use `a = np.append(a, ...)` (and you'll then find that that `for` loop is horrifically slow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem is `range(0, 25000000)` because this creates a list composed of `int`s.

The memory needed for containing such a list is (for simplicity assuming 32bytes per integer) `25kk * 32B = 800kkB ~ 762MB`.

Use the generator-like `xrange` or update to python3 there `range` is a bit less memory expensive (because there the values are not precomputed but evaluated when needed).

The actual numpy array is always empty (since you only create a temporary copy with `np.append` - the result of the append is not stored and therefore discarded directly afterwards!) and therefore negligable.

I would work with your `a = np.random.random_integers(1, 25000000, size=25000000)` and convert it (if you want) to `np.uint` afterwards.

Comment: Your size calculation seems to be assuming that the 32 in `int32` means it takes 32 bytes. It doesn't; the "32" number is bits. Also, Python 2 ints aren't necessarily 32-bit. A Python 2 int takes more like 12 or 24 bytes, depending on whether you're on 32-bit or 64-bit Python. It requires space for the `PyObject_HEAD`, the `long` that stores the actual data, and structure padding. There's also the extra 4 or 8 bytes required for the pointer in the list, which don't count towards the 12/24 number.

Comment: That said, the `range` looks like it should be the source of essentially all the memory consumption.

Comment: Also, `xrange` objects aren't generators. Generators are a specific type of iterator, and `xrange` objects aren't even iterators. `xrange` objects are best described as lazy iterables.

Comment: @user2357112 - Thanks for the input, I haven't known ``xrange`` is not a generator! I have updated the answer.

Comment: Solved. Thank you MSeifert. Indeed, when changing the loop to a manual incrementation using `while i < 25000000` and `i += 1`, the memory usage is as expected.